# JPQL Query - object that's in one list and isn't in another

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I want to find list of entities that are present in the first list and reject entities if they exists in second list.
Example data:
I've got Products: P1,P2 and P3. Another (main) entity is Items: I1 and I2. I1 entity contains P1, and P2 and I2 contains P2 and P3. I want to find list of Items, if they're present in List1(contains just P1) and reject every Item if it's present in List2(contains just P3). So it should give me I1 as output.
My query and code:

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT distinct(i) FROM Item i join fetch i.products ip WHERE ip.product IN :list1 AND ip.product NOT IN :list2");
    query.setParameter("list1", list1);
    query.setParameter("list2", list2);
```

This query gives me list of both Items. What's wrong here?

Comment: You are setting the value of `list1` parameter twice in the code, is this a typo or the real code?

Comment: It's a typo, goin to correct it immediately

Comment: is "I" really the column name you want displayed from the item table? It appears to be the alias of the table.  perhaps you mean `distinct *` or `distinct i.id?`  I think this would likely throw a syntax error.  Are you error trapping? if so what error are you getting or does this simply return an empty set?  Lastly, I'm not sure but it seems like a `outer join` would work better here, or even an `exists` statement.

Comment: "i" is the alias of the table I guess that this part of the query is OK. It's going to return an empty set, it throws an error only if any (or both) of lists are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct i FROM Item i join fetch i.products ip WHERE :list1 IN ip and :list2 NOT IN ip
```

**UPDATE**

I've been trying to get this to work myself, but with no results. @NeilStockton suggested it is not supported in JPA specification.

However, in your example you have parameter lists with one element. In case of single element parameters, this should work:

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT distinct i FROM Item i join fetch i.products ip WHERE :param1 IN elements(ip) and :param2 NOT IN elements(ip)");

query.setParameter("param1", product1);
query.setParameter("param2", product2);
```

Comment: Idea marks error at ip after :list1 and says: `'(' or <input parameter> expected, got ip`

Comment: A List cannot be in a List, as per the JPA spec.

Comment: @NeilStockton Didn't check the spec (do you have a link?), but trying out various combinations didn't produce any result. I'll update my answer.

Comment: For the spec, http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html  or alternatively at the end of http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/jpql.html  which defines the BNF for the query language (copied from the spec), search for "in_expression"

Comment: @ZZ5 It seems this is not supported. I've updated my answer with a alternative, if it fits your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I'll mark that as correct answer, to work with lists I guess I'll have one query that will return all entities that are present in first list and then filter it manually to remove all the entities which are present in the second list.